# Issue in Command line argument/String to unzip .7z files when filename contains space

Tags: vb.net, cmd, unzip, 7zip

I checked .7z website FAQ and other related website for my issue. But didn't find best solution for this issue.
When .7z filename has no space then my cmd is running perfectecly for Unzip. But when zip foldername contain space then its not working.

```
Dim args As String = "e " + """" + zipFileFolder + """" + " -o" + ToFolder + "" + " -p""Password123""" + " -aoa"
```

example: Zip file name:

> 3344-2633-9058-4583_37DB40L1KLJU_15_07_2017__18_40_39_FSserviceLog.7z

then it is running perfectly but for this file name:

> 6530-0567-9050-2878
>   AVsetting_WD-WXS1A176FF0E_15_05_2017__17_57_37-F6serviceLog.7z

where space is there between 2878 and AVsetting, then my cmd is not working. Please guild me for this.

Please check following code:

```
Function extract7z(zipFileFolder As String, ToFolder As String)
        Try
            Dim args As String = "e " & """" & zipFileFolder & """" & " -o" & ToFolder & "" & " -p""cyberspa123""" & " -aoa"
            Dim p As New Process
            Dim pInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
            pInfo.FileName = exePath
            pInfo.Arguments = args
            pInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            p.StartInfo = pInfo
            p.Start()
            p.WaitForExit()
            '   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exePath, args)
            'Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            ' System.IO.File.Delete(zipFileFolder)
            For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(ToFolder)
                Dim check As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(foundFile)
                If (check = ".7z") Then
                    Dim zipFolderpath1 As String = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ToFolder & "/" & System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(foundFile))
                    extract7z(foundFile, zipFolderpath1)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)

        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: can you just remove spaces from the filename?

Comment: What does _"not working"_ mean? Does it give you any errors? Could you show us how you start the process as well?

Comment: Your not the first but you really haven't put a lot of thought into that string concatenation. Why would you concatenate two string literals and why would you ever concatenation an empty string to something? You should also use `&` rather than `+` for string concatenation. `Dim args As String = "e """ & zipFileFolder & """ -o" & ToFolder & " -p""Password123"" -aoa"`. That's immediately more readable and thus less error-prone. `String.Format or string interpolation would improve it further. As for the issue, what exactly does `args` contain when it fails and how exactly are you using it?

Comment: @TrevorBrooks: I cannot do it. File Name is using somewhere else for further processing as well.

Comment: @VisualVincent: Please check edited question. I just add. You may try this command in your cmd as well.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Thank you for your inputs. i will keep in mind. For further please check edited question. No any error is coming during unzip command. It simply just not making unzip file in destination folder if space is found in zip file name.

Comment: any solution for this issue? Appreciate if some one guide me. Thank you.

Comment: your question and it's solution helped me a lot. Thank you.